# Insert Statement in Oracle Procedure is not working properly

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am try to do the insert into a table inside the oracle store procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_TEST
IS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO tab1 
   SELECT ename,empid,mgr FROM EMP;
   COMMIT;
END;

BEGIN
   sp_test;
END;
```

but some of the columns are completely insert null data where as if I run the the following statement independently it is working fine.

```
INSERT INTO tab1 
SELECT ename,empid,mgr FROM EMP;
```

I will appreciate for help.

Comment: Are `ename`, `empid`, and `mgr` the first three fields in `TAB1`? It would help if you would **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the tags and include the DDL for `EMP` and `TAB1`. Thanks.

Comment: Try debugging by adding the following in the procedure, `SELECT ename,empid,mgr INTO v_ename,v_empid,v_mgr FROM EMP;` Do not forget to declare the variables such as `v_ename,v_empid,v_mgr` before `BEGIN`. Additionally include `DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line` to see the output.

Comment: Thanks for replying...As I mention the statement INSERT INTO tab1 SELECT ename,empid,mgr FROM EMP; is working fine ... its only SP where I am getting this issue. Also I try all option still in SP some field are coming as NULL